# How to prove this convergence proposition?

Tags: real-analysis

'$x_n\gt0,$  $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$converges$\to x_n^\frac1n $ converges'

How to prove this proposition?

What i think is to use

when  $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L$

$ x_{n+1}\le...\le (L+l)^{n-k}x_{k+1} $ something like this

but i failed.

Comment: Are you familiar with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean ?

Comment: How can use Cesàro mean?

Comment: If you apply the cesaro mean to $U_n$ like in my answer, when you take the sum in the cesaro mean the terms will cancel each others due to the fact that log will transform the ratio into a difference

Comment: Try to do that for $L \neq 0$ there is obviously a problem if $L=0$ so you wont be able to take the logarithm

Edit : actually I think it's fine even if $L=0$

Comment: Why it's fine if $L=0$? If than $U_n$ diverge

Comment: Yes, $U_n$ goes to $- \infty$ but Cesaro Mean still applies and it will be 0 once you go back to exponential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : use the [Cesaro Mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) applied to $U_n = \ln{(x_{n+1}/x_n)}$.

If needed the proof for Cesaro mean can be found [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean#Proof)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a_n$ is a sequences of positive terms. Then:

$$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le\liminf_{n\to \infty} a_n^{1/n}\le\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n^{1/n}\le\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

We have three inequalities  but the inequality in the middle is trivial. So only we concern about the others, note that the proof of the first and last are very similar.

1) Let $a = \liminf_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1}/a_n$. Plainly $a\ge0$. If $a=0$, there is nothing to prove. So we may assume $a>0$. Let $0<\alpha<a$, then there is a integer $n_0$ such that

$$\alpha<a_{k+1}/a_k \tag{1}$$ 
for all $k\ge n_0$. Let $n> n_0$, then we get multiplying these inequalities in (1)

$$a_n/a_{n_0}>\alpha^{n-n_0} \; \text{and}\;\left(a_{n_0}\alpha^{-n_0}\right)^{1/n} \alpha< a_n^{1/n}$$

Since this hold for all $n> n_0$, then $ \alpha\le \liminf a_n^{1/n}$. But $\alpha $ is an arbitrary number $<a$. Then $a\le  \liminf a_n^{1/n}$. If $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L$ so $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are equal and the result is trivial by the inequality.